# automatize using keyconfig by creating a keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have a question concerning keyconfig

I have always the same page and I always have the same categories to open each in a new tabs in that page. I wanted to know if I can automatize that using keyconfig by creating a keyboard shortcuts.